# impossible to convert type observable <type> to type <type>

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to use Angular Subject type to create a shared data service between different component.

I started by creating my Subject variable

```
  private returnedDataSubject = new Subject<FilmCard>();
```

then set a subscribe to that observable

```
  returnedData = this.returnedDataSubject.asObservable();
  getList() {
    this.returnedDataSubject.next(<FilmCard> this.httpClient.get<FilmCard>(this.url));
  }
```

I get an Error on VisualCode:

```
Impossible de convertir le type 'Observable<FilmCard>' en type 'FilmCard'. 

impossible to convert type 'Observable<FilmCard> to type <FilmCard>
```

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://blog.cloudboost.io/build-simple-shopping-cart-with-angular-4-observables-subject-subscription-part-2-2d3735cde5f)

Comment: The message is clear: you're trying to call next(), which expects a FilmCard, with the result of `this.httpClient.get<FilmCard>(this.url)`, which is not a FilmCard, but an Observable<FilmCard>. So that can't compile. The code should simply be `this.httpClient.get<FilmCard>(this.url).subscribe(this.returnedDataSubject);`. Read http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject

Comment: you have to pass a value to .next not an observable

Comment: @JBNizet when I `console.log(this.returnedDataSubject)` I don't get the value returned by the httpRequest

Comment: logging an observable makes no sense. It's not a value. It's a pipeline of operations emitting events asynchronously. You need to read about observables.